How to attach a custom domain to an HTTP API Gateway (apigatewayv2) using the CDK?
I'm not sure if this is a bug or if I am doing something wrong but I keep getting exceptions when I try to attach a custom domain and add mappings to my API gateway.
Exception using ApiMapping:

9:02:44 a.m. | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::ApiGatewayV2::ApiMapping        | ApiMapping
Resource handler returned message: "Invalid domain name identifier specified (Service: AmazonApiGatewayV2; Status Code: 404; Error Code: No
tFoundException; Request ID: <REQUEST_ID>; Proxy: null)" (RequestToken: <REQUEST_TOKEN>, HandlerErrorCode: GeneralServiceException)

Exception using defaultDomainMapping:

8:58:56 a.m. | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::ApiGatewayV2::ApiMapping        | API/Default...omainNameundefined
Resource handler returned message: "Invalid domain name identifier specified (Service: AmazonApiGatewayV2; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NotFoundException; Request ID: <REQUEST_ID>; Proxy: null)" (RequestToken: <REQUEST_TOKEN>, HandlerErrorCode: GeneralServiceException)

Here is my code:
export class APIStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: APIStackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    // Custom Domain
    const apiDomainName = `api.${props.appName}.${props.rootDomain}`;

    const hostedZone = HostedZone.fromLookup(this, "HostedZone", {
      domainName: props.rootDomain,
    });

    const domainCertificate = new Certificate(
      this,
      `${props.appName}-Certificate`,
      {
        domainName: apiDomainName,
        certificateName: `${props.appName}-Certificate`,
        validation: CertificateValidation.fromDns(hostedZone),
      }
    );

    // Custom domain for API
    const gatewayDomain = new DomainName(this, `${props.appName}-DomainName`, {
      domainName: apiDomainName,
      certificate: domainCertificate,
      endpointType: EndpointType.REGIONAL,
    });

    // Security
    const apiAuthorizer = new HttpUserPoolAuthorizer(
      `${props.appName}-APIAuthorizer`,
      props.userPool,
      { userPoolClients: [props.appClient] }
    );

    // API
    const httpApi = new HttpApi(this, `${props.appName}-API`, {
      defaultAuthorizer: apiAuthorizer,
    });

    new ApiMapping(this, "Mapping", {
      domainName: gatewayDomain,
      api: httpApi,
    });

    // route53 records
    new ARecord(this, `${props.appName}-AliasRecord`, {
      zone: hostedZone,
      recordName: apiDomainName,
      target: RecordTarget.fromAlias(
        new ApiGatewayv2DomainProperties(
          gatewayDomain.regionalDomainName,
          gatewayDomain.regionalHostedZoneId
        )
      ),
    });

    // Lambdas
    const testLambda = new NodejsFunction(this, `${props.appName}-TestLambda`, {
      runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_20_X,
      handler: "handler",
      functionName: `${props.appName}-test-function`,
      entry: path.join(__dirname, "../lambdas/endpoints/test", "index.ts"),
    });

    // Registering routes
    const testLambdaIntegration = new HttpLambdaIntegration(
      "TestLambdaIntegration",
      testLambda
    );

    httpApi.addRoutes({
      path: "/test",
      methods: [HttpMethod.GET],
      integration: testLambdaIntegration,
      authorizer: apiAuthorizer,
    });
  }
}

The error occurs when I create the ApiMapping and, from what I can tell, CloudFormation is trying to create the mapping before the domain for the API Gateway (gatewayDomain) has been created and propogated. I've tried explicitly adding a dependency to create the domain before creating the mapping, but it still does not work:
apiMapping.node.addDependency(gatewayDomain)
I have found that  creating the mapping using the console, or using the aws cli works but I'd like to use the cdk for this. Any help would be appreciate :)

I've removed my answer as it was incorrect. Are you sure that no other API is using that domain name? Is the certificate being created and validated properly? Can you try creating the cert in a separate stack and making sure it's validated, then passing it to your API stack? Also - do you have upper-case letters in the domain?

The issue was that I had upper-case characters in my domain. Wow, thank you so much for your help, I appreciate it :)

Glad it helped. I'm marking it as a duplicate of another question, which contains the solution
